# Why is Python throwing this error on Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make a script that needs to login to a specific account. After research, most of the websites told me to use selenium / webdriver.

My code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
```

Then it's just finding the elements of username and password etc.

The line above give me a syntax error,
without specifying anything else.
What is wrong exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Before using the `driver` object you have to instantiate it with something like this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
```